# json-ld for Javascript popup window content

Tags: javascript, schema.org, json-ld

1. on our website, products details page open via a Javascript popup window.
2. that same product page may be opened with a direct link to that page with the popup window opened.

In the above scenario #2 my json-ld data is loaded fine and Google structured data testing tool picks up the information.

However in the most common scenario i.e. scenario #1 above the json-ld data doesn't seem to load and the product information is null.

Example - scenerio 1: http://www.beride.net/school/guincho-adventours
Example - scenerio 2: http://www.beride.net/school/guincho-adventours?course=62

I used Google Tag manager to fire up the json-ld scripts

Does anyone know I can can get the json-ld information to load in the above scenario #1?

Answer (score 0):

The Structured Data Testing Tool is not 100% at coping with JavaScript including the Google Tag Manager. Either post in rendered html to the tool or look at the Structured Data report in the Google Search Consoles.

Your first example is a list of products. Googles guides indicate that you should not mark up complete entities when they are listed as summaries that link to the details. They suggest you mark up a list of links.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings

Comment: thank you.
I'll wait to see what Google Search console captures then.